# How to generate a rolling mean for a specific date range and location with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops

I have a large data set with names of stores, dates and profits. 
My data set is not the most organized but I now have it in this df.

df

```
Store   Date           Profit 
ABC     May 1 2018     234    
XYZ     May 1 2018     410
AZY     May 1 2018     145
ABC     May 2 2018     234    
XYZ     May 2 2018     410
AZY     May 2 2018     145
```

I proudly created a function to get each day into one df by itself until I realized it would be very time consuming to do one for each day.

```
def avg(n):
  return df.loc[df['Date'] == "May" + " " + str(n) + " " +str(2018)]
```

where n would be the date I want to get.  So that function get me just the dates I want.

What I really need is to have a way to get all dates I want in a list and to append them to a pd for each day. I tried doing this but did not work out.

```
def avg(n):
    dlist= []
    for i in n:
        dlist= df.loc[df['Date'] == "May" + " " + str(i) + " "  +str(2018)]
        dlist=pd.DataFrame(dlist)
        dlist.append(i)
        return dlist

df2=avg([21,23,24,25])
```

My goal there was to have all the dates of (21,23,24,25) for the May
into its own series of df.

But it was a total fail got this error

> cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

I am not sure if it's also possible to add a rolling average or mean, to columns for each day of (21,23,24,25), but that's where analysis will conclude.

output desired

```
 Store   Date           Profit   Rolling Mean 
  ABC     May 1 2018     234     250
  XYZ     May 1 2018     410     401
  AZY     May 1 2018     145     415
```

where the rolling mean is for the past 30 days. Above all, I would like to have each day into its own df where I can save it to csv file the end.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but in the `avg()` function, the `for` loop has a `return` statement inside it, which terminates the function immediately.  That loop will only ever run once.

Answer (score 2):

## Rolling Mean:

- The example data given in the question, has data in the format of `May 1 2018`, which can't be used for rolling.  Rolling requires a `datetime` index.

  - Instead of string splitting the original `Date` column, it should be converted to `datetime`, using `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`, which will give dates in the format `2018-05-01`
  - With a properly formatted `datetime` column, use `df['Day'] = df.Date.dt.day` and `df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.month_name()` to get a `Day` and `Month` column, if desired.

### Given the original data:

#### Original Data:

```py
Store        Date  Profit
  ABC  May 1 2018     234
  XYZ  May 1 2018     410
  AZY  May 1 2018     145
  ABC  May 2 2018     234
  XYZ  May 2 2018     410
  AZY  May 2 2018     145
```

#### Transformed Original Data:

```py
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Day'] = df.Date.dt.day
df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.month_name()

Store       Date  Profit  Day Month
  ABC 2018-05-01     234    1   May
  XYZ 2018-05-01     410    1   May
  AZY 2018-05-01     145    1   May
  ABC 2018-05-02     234    2   May
  XYZ 2018-05-02     410    2   May
  AZY 2018-05-02     145    2   May
```

### Rolling Example:

- The example dataset is insufficient to produce a 30-day rolling average
- In order to have a 30-day rolling mean, there needs to be more than 30 days of data for each store (i.e. on the 31st day, you get the 1st mean, for the previous 30 days)
- The following example will setup a dataframe consisting of every day in 2018, a random profit between 100 and 1001, and a random store, chosen from `['ABC', 'XYZ', 'AZY']`.

#### Extended Sample:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

list_of_dates = [date for date in np.arange(datetime(2018, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 1), timedelta(days=1)).astype(datetime)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Store': [random.choice(['ABC', 'XYZ', 'AZY']) for _ in range(365)],
                   'Date': list_of_dates,
                   'Profit': [np.random.randint(100, 1001) for _ in range(365)]})

Store       Date  Profit
  ABC 2018-01-01     901
  AZY 2018-01-02     540
  AZY 2018-01-03     417
  XYZ 2018-01-04     280
  XYZ 2018-01-05     384
  XYZ 2018-01-06     104
  XYZ 2018-01-07     691
  ABC 2018-01-08     376
  XYZ 2018-01-09     942
  XYZ 2018-01-10     297

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df_rolling = df.groupby(['Store']).rolling(30).mean()
df_rolling.rename(columns={'Profit': '30-Day Rolling Mean'}, inplace=True)
df_rolling.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

#### `df_rolling.head()`:

- Note the first 30-days for each store, will be NaN

```py
Store       Date  30-Day Rolling Mean
  ABC 2018-01-01                  NaN
  ABC 2018-01-03                  NaN
  ABC 2018-01-07                  NaN
  ABC 2018-01-11                  NaN
  ABC 2018-01-13                  NaN
```

#### `df_rolling.tail()`:

```py
Store       Date  30-Day Rolling Mean
  XYZ 2018-12-17           556.966667
  XYZ 2018-12-18           535.633333
  XYZ 2018-12-19           534.733333
  XYZ 2018-12-24           551.066667
  XYZ 2018-12-27           572.033333
```

#### Plot:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
g = sns.lineplot(x='Date', y='30-Day Rolling Mean', data=df_rolling, hue='Store')
for item in g.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(60)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Alternatively: A dataframe for each store:

- It's also possible to create a separate dataframe for each store and put it inside a `dict`
- This alternative makes is easier to plot a more detailed graph with less code

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

list_of_dates = [date for date in np.arange(datetime(2018, 1, 1), datetime(2019, 1, 1), timedelta(days=1)).astype(datetime)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Store': [random.choice(['ABC', 'XYZ', 'AZY']) for _ in range(365)],
                   'Date': list_of_dates,
                   'Profit': [np.random.randint(100, 1001) for _ in range(365)]})

df_dict = dict()
for store in df.Store.unique():
    df_dict[store] = df[['Date', 'Profit']][df.Store == store]
    df_dict[store].set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df_dict[store]['Profit: 30-Day Rolling Mean'] = df_dict[store].rolling(30).mean()

print(df_dict.keys())

>>> dict_keys(['ABC', 'XYZ', 'AZY'])

print(df_dict['ABC'].head())
```

[image]

#### Plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(13, 8), sharex=True)

for k, v in df_dict.items():
    axes.plot(v['Profit'], marker='.', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label=k)
    axes.plot(v['Profit: 30-Day Rolling Mean'], marker='o', markersize=4, linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label=f'{k} Rolling')

axes.legend()
axes.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.ylabel('Profit ($)')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.title('Recorded Profit vs. 30-Day Rolling Mean of Profit')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Get a dataframe for a specific month:

- Recall, this is randomly generated data, so the stores don't have data for every day of the month.

```py
may_df = dict()

for k, v in df_dict.items():
    v.reset_index(inplace=True)
    may_df[k] = v[v.Date.dt.month_name() == 'May']
    may_df[k].set_index('Date', inplace=True)

print(may_df['XYZ'])
```

[image]

#### Plot: May data only:

[image]

### Save dataframes:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```py
may_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
may_df.to_csv('may.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution may be **groupby()**
Check out this example :

```
import pandas as pd

listt = [['a',2,3],
        ['b',5,7],
        ['a',3,9],
        ['a',1,3],
        ['b',9,4],
        ['a',4,7],
        ['c',7,2],
        ['a',2,5],
        ['c',4,7],
        ['b',5,5]]

my_df = pd.DataFrame(listt)
my_df.columns=['Class','Day_1','Day_2']

my_df.groupby('Class')['Day_1'].mean()
```

OutPut :

```
Class
a    2.400000
b    6.333333
c    5.500000
Name: Day_1, dtype: float64
```

**Note** : Similarly You can **Group** your data by **Date** and get **Average** of your **Profit**.

Comment: thanks. I did my_df.groupby(["Store", "Date"])['profit'].mean() but it included stores that were closed and thus had profits of 0. The good news is if the store is closed its not in the data. But it still has it because that date exits and just assignments it a value of 0.